# Unable to click on android.widget.ImageButton

Tags: java, eclipse, android-emulator, appium

I have tried following locators

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc='Open navigation drawer']")).click();
or
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@index='0'])")).click();
or
driver.findElementByXPath("(//android.view.ViewGroup)[1]").click();
```

[image: Click on highlighted button]

Download=[Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opentap)

> Not able to click on image button.

```
@Test
public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> Loging() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

    File file = new File("src/test/java", "opentap-v1.1-28012019.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Pixel_C_Edited_API_28");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, file.getAbsolutePath());
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
            capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.opentap:id/btn_go")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("kaustubh.patil");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("opentapuat");
    driver.findElement(By.id("rememberMe")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("kc-login")).click();
    // driver.findElement(By.id("com.opentap:id/btn_go")).click();
    // Thread.sleep(10000);
    // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@index='0'])")).click();
    // driver.findElementByXPath("(//android.view.ViewGroup)[1]").click();

    // WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);
    // WebElement element =
    // wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("com.opentap:id/add")));
    /*
     * try { Thread.sleep(1000); WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
     * wait.until(driver .findElement(By.
     * xpath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc='Open navigation drawer']")
     * )); } catch (Throwable error) {
     * Assert.fail("Timeout waiting for Page Load Request to complete."); }
     */
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc='Open navigation drawer']")).click();
    return driver;
}
```

[image: DOM]

Comment: What is reporting the unable to click?  Can you try to separate the step by creating an AndroidElement or MobileElement first, then using it's click method?

Comment: We need to know the error. Is the element even found? You can't click what you can't find. Share the DOM while you're at it.

Comment: Here is showing exception: Not implemented yet for script.

Comment: When you find the element using the above locators (content-desc is your best option), are you getting a result? We need to separate the find from the click.

Comment: Could you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use touch action class & pointers to perform your requirement. Use below snippet it will work perfectly for every app which has drawar navigation bar(I have tried for many apps, worked pretty fine).

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
action.tap (10, 100).perform();
```

Here, 10 is X pointer, 100 is Y pointer. why i given x as 10  is, that drawar image will be located between 0-15 range & you have to make sure for drawar location also(for some apps it might comes in right side, then you have to give coordinates accordingly).

Comment: Tapping based on pixels is a last resort. This changes based on device, operating system, and orientation. If you must perform a tap, at least find your coordinates based on a known element. We still don't know if he can find any elements so we should start there.